# Will lower casing all canonical url solve duplicate issue

Tags: seo, google-search-console, duplicate-content, canonical-url, case-sensitive

The website I'm working on can have both upper and lower case URLs, even though they will produce the exact same content.  eg: http://www.example.com/uk/office-space/london/soho and http://www.example.com/uk/office-space/london/SOHO Will both produce the same search results for the area "Soho".

I have just placed a "Lower Case" [canonical url](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en) in the all the pages now seeing as Google was obviously complaining about "duplicate" results.  After almost 4 weeks these pages are still listed as being duplicate even though the Canonical URL is lower case (even for the uppercase links)

Is there something else I should do, will this "canonical URL" work, or should I just wait a little longer for Google to update my index in Google Webmaster Tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same situation ( a webshop), just wait. I also 301 all the uppercased paged to the lowercase version, that might speed things up.

- Make sure you canonical all pages
- Header 301 all pages to the lowercase
- Make sure your sitemap is up to date
- Make sure all inpage anchors are correct

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I thought it might be a bit of a waiting game. Just to be on the safe side, I will try and 301 all those "uppercase" pages to their "lowercase" ones.